# Using [UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:] doesn't work with UITableView seperatorColor?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

I'm trying to configure a dark gray seperator color. Why does the following do nothing?

```
self.tableView.seperatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeperatorStyleSingleLine;
self.tableView.seperatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 127 green:127 blue:127 alpha:1];
```

returns a table with no seperators at all.

As soon as I use *[UIColor blackColor]* then I get seperators just fine. What's the deal?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You need to divide by `255.0`

Because I hardly ever use values between 1.0 and 0.0, I created a very simple UIColor category that does the messy looking division by itself: (from http://github.com/Jon889/JPGeneral)

```
//.h file
@interface UIColor (JPExtras)
+ (UIColor *)colorWithR:(CGFloat)red G:(CGFloat)green B:(CGFloat)blue A:(CGFloat)alpha;
@end

//.m file
@implementation UIColor (JPExtras)
+ (UIColor *)colorWithR:(CGFloat)red G:(CGFloat)green B:(CGFloat)blue A:(CGFloat)alpha {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0) green:(green/255.0) blue:(blue/255.0) alpha:alpha];
}
@end
```

So you can just do(If you import the category I linked to above):

```
[UIColor colorWithR:127 G:127: B:127 A:1];
```

Comment: Is a value of 0-1 standard in the industry? You can open up any photo editing application and the color picker gives you a value from 0-255, regardless I'm curious as to why they would make you do the extra work dividing?

Comment: @Nick - that's a good question. I suspect it's because `UIColor` needs to support 'deep color' (that is, colors with a depth greater than 24 bit, or 32 with alpha). Of course, that still doesn't change the fact a built-in convenience method (along with hex support) would clearly be quite helpful to many developers!

Comment: also, the same works for hex values. as sometimes we get the colors as hex, in order to not calculate them by hand we can use: for example for #C94557 it would be: [UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)0xC9/0xFF green:(CGFloat)0x45/0xFF blue:(CGFloat)0x57/0xFF alpha:1.0];

Comment: There are two new methods in UIColor that accept integer values from 0 to 255. See my answer below.

Answer (score 59):

Because your UIColor method requires a float from 0-1, not 0-255. You need to divide all your RGB values by 255.0, as follows:

```
self.tableView.seperatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:127.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to divide your values with 255, because the range is 0-1. Take 127/255 = 0.49f and type in that instead. It's there, it's just white :)

edit: cause of comments, I added some code as to how I solve it:

```
-(float)getRGBValue:(int) rgbValue{  
    return rgbValue/255.0;
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two new methods in `UIColor` that accept integer values from 0 to 255:

```
UIColor(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int)
```

and

```
UIColor(alpha: Float, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int)
```

It's not in the documentation but I've used it and it works like a charm.