# BackgroundColor of UItableviewCell Notworking

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

I am setting the Background color of my uitableviewCell like

```
 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0 green:210.0 blue:11.0 alpha:1.0];
```

its not working, however, if i do like

```
 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

it works then. Any help

Comment: Please look at the docs for colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:, and note the values the parameters take.

Comment: You need to divide by 255.0
Please refer to this article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641523/using-uicolor-colorwithredgreenbluealpha-doesnt-work-with-uitableview-sep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIColor` has to be defined **between 0 and 1** to get the **RGB** value to work ([UIColor class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a)):

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0f/255.0f green:210.0f/255.0f blue:11.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```