# change background when a new game begins objective c

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Iam making a simple game with Sprite Kit, and I want to change background every time game begins, for example, when a new game begins, background  is blue, but when hero dies and start new game background is yellow. Before that, i made SKTextureAtlas of img, that flash when hero dies, maybe i can change some code, so it fit my needs?
here sample of my code:

```
    SKTextureAtlas *atlas =[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"back"];
    SKTexture *back0 = [atlas textureNamed:@"back0@2x"];
    SKTexture *back1 = [atlas textureNamed:@"back1@2x"];
    SKTexture *back2 = [atlas textureNamed:@"back2@2x"];
    SKTexture *back3 = [atlas textureNamed:@"back3@2x"];
  NSArray *backatlas = @[back0, back1, back2, back3];
    SKAction *backatlasanimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:backatlas timePerFrame:0.1];
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.1];
    SKAction *backaction = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, backatlasanimation]];
    [background runAction:backaction];
    [self addChild:background];
```

Well, i do my research and come up with this:

```
-(NSarray *)background{
if(!_background){ 
_background = @[[SKColor redColor], [SKColor yellowColor], [SKColor grayColor]];
}
return _background ;
}
//// Add some random, so color change.
-(SKColor *) randomColorBack {
int index = arc4random() % [self.backgrounds count];
return self.backgrounds[index];
} 
......
background.color = [self randomColor];
background.colorBlendFactor = 1.0;
```

But how to do this with images, and is it good idea, to use original colors what xcode provides in game?

Comment: Are you trying to randomize a background color by using predefined set of colors , or there is no predefined colors and all colors are allowed when randomizing ? Or you are trying to randomize background image (change texture) ? If your images are just monochromes, then there is no need to use textures for that. Just change backgroundColor property.

Comment: @Whirlwind there only predefined set of colors, but yeah, i want to set background with images not colors, images are monochromes, but Sprite kit don't provide that kind of colors that i need

Comment: You are wrong. You can create any color you want. You just have to provide right value for red,green, blue and alpha component. Let me write an example for you.

Comment: @Whirlwind yes please, that would be great if you do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have predefined set of colors, then you have to use your favourite image editor to find out each component (red, green, blue, alpha) of desired color. So, if you open Photoshop for example, and use its color picker tool, you will end up seeing something like

**R**:123,**B**:234, **G**:125

These represent values of each color component for the chosen color.

In order to make a color with specified color components, you can use some of UIColor class methods and according to the docs, 
[+ colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:) is just perfect for this. It accepts values from 0 to 1 so, this is how you should create your colors:

```
UIColor* customColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(120/255.0f) green:(23/255.0f) blue:(32/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
```

Not really needed, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642229/3402095) you can see a convenient method which accepts values from 0 to 255, so everything might be a bit easier to use:

That would be it. Just fill some array with these predefined colors and choose a random one. In the case you want to randomize color (without predefined set of colors), use this :

```
-(UIColor*)getRandomColor{

    CGFloat red = arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat green = arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0f;
    CGFloat blue = arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0f;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green: green blue:blue alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know i can do that.